# How to force https with .htaccess on pages with certain URL string

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-redirect

I've checked many posts related to this topic, but I they didn't work as I expected, so... this is my question:

I have several pages with this pattern in my website:

```
http://example.com/newsletter/[variable_substring]
```

And I need to force all of those urls that contain "**/newsletter/**" as a part of the url to use "**https://**" protocol instead "**http://**" (if they are accessed by http://, of course).

I need to do this in the .htaccess. Anybody knows what exactly I had to type in?

Regards,

Comment: Notice that I think my website goes out over internet through a proxy server in Germany. Also note that when I print PHP's $_SERVER['HTTPS'], I always got 'http'. Sounds like whatever I do I'll always get 'http'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to .htaccess

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/newsletter/(.*)$ https://%1/newsletter/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]`

Also in httpd.conf add `AllowOverride All` for this directory

Comment: I tried it with your code and it didn't do anything. The url doesn't changes to https protocol. Also note I have no access to the httpd.conf file. It is managed by a third-party team.

Comment: May be rewrite engine is disabled? Add to .htaccess `RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^/newsletter/$ /newsletter1/ [R=301,QSA,L]`. If browser will redirect from `http://domain/newsletter/` to `http://domain/newsletter1/`, rewrite engine is enabled.

Comment: .htaccess should be placed in the root directory, not in newsletter directory

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is 'http' for http and https requests?

Comment: I saw a 'RewriteEngine On' sentence already in my htaccess. So I added the rest of your code below. However, no redirect to '/newsletter1/' was performed. I got exactly the same url. And, as an answer to your question, I did a `<?php print $_SERVER['HTTPS']; ?>`, but nothing was printed. What's wrong with this?

Comment: `<?php print $_SERVER['HTTPS']; ?>` should print "on" if script is requested via https

Comment: I tried on my system and found that rules dont work with mandatory first slash in url. Try `RewriteRule ^/?newsletter/(.*) /newsletter1/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]`

Comment: Yeah, now it appends a "1" to the url. So, I attempt to do the same with your original post, but, I also get a redirect loop. This is the code I used:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?newsletter/(.*)$ https://%1/newsletter/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]`

Comment: redirect loop http->https->http->https or https->https->https->https?

Comment: Hi @Max P., I don't see my page looping between HTTPS <-> HTTP, so I think that the answer is the second one: HTTPS <->HTTPS.

Comment: It is strange, may be you have proxy in front of you server that internally redirects from https to http.. :) Try to delete rewrite rules in .htaccess, make php script with code `<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTPS"].' - '.$_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"].' - '.getenv("HTTPS").' - '.getenv("REQUEST_SCHEME"); ?>` and request it through https. You should see `on - https - on - https` as output. If not, request was not made through https. Also you can look at logs, if they are separate for http and https.

Comment: Hi Max P., I did you told me in previous comment. This is what I see on my screen, after your code snippet was executed: "- - -". The result is the same accesing the url both with a 'http' and 'https'. So, may be is  caused by something related to the proxy of my company? How could do I fix it?

Comment: Look if output for script with code `<?php var_dump($_SERVER); ?>` with http and https differs. May be https has header `X-Forwarded-Proto` or something like that, so it could be possible to add this condition in rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
#if the https is off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
#and the request is /newsletter/...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/newsletter/
#then redirect it to https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Hi @Starkeen, Please read my previous comment. Your code seems to work, but I get a redirect loop in my browser. Due to I can't determine if I'm browsing in 'http' or 'https' cause by the Proxy. Am I right? So, if true, what could I do to solve my problem?

Comment: There is no problem with the code I posted. Redirect loop error occurs when a url is pointing to itself I dont think my code is doing that. May be your other rules are conflicting with this.

Comment: I think so too. My htaccess is an 'standard' .htaccess file from a Drupal 7 installation. I didn't make any modification on it, but this one. I still guessing it's something related to the server configuration, don't you?